# The difference between Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(command) and new Thread(command).start();

Tags: java, multithreading

Well title says it, what is the difference between `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(command)` and `new Thread(command).start();`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Behaviourally, pretty much nothing.

However, once you have an `Executor` instance, you can submit multiple tasks to it, and have them executed one after another. You can't do that simply with a raw `Thread`.

Comment: "Behaviourally, pretty much nothing." is totally wrong statement. There is huge behavioral difference. See my answer below

Comment: What about reuse of thread vs creating multiple threads?

Answer (score 27):

One noticeable difference, is when you run `new Thread(someRunnable).start();` when the runnable is finished the thread will die quietly.

The Executor though will persist until you shut it down.  So running `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(command)` When you think your application or the JVM may be finished the Executor may still be running in a background thread.

Comment: Apparently not the case: https://www.farside.org.uk/201309/learning_from_bad_code

Comment: Interesting, I can't argue with much of what he says. I can't recreate the `finalize` call after the `submit` completes. I ran a simple `main` Test and the delegating TPE is never GC'd.

Comment: I haven't tested it to be honest.

Comment: why do you mention the JVM? if the JVM is dead, there is no process, hence no application, hence no thread or executor.

Answer (score 15):

With `Executor.execute`, if an `Error` or `RuntimeException` is thrown in the `Executor` it will be swallowed silently, while the `new Thread()` will print it to `System.err`.

Comment: One solution, to avoid having exceptions swallowed by the executor, is to call `Executor.submit` instead of `execute`, then call `get` on the resulting `Future` when you want to handle the potential errors.

Comment: @Lii Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 7):

There can be many differences, but I will show you one difference which I found very important to understand:

```
public void sendEventSingleThreadExecutor(Event e){
  Executor.singleThreadExecutor().execute(()->{//send the event here})
}
```

Now, even if you **call** sendEventSingleThreadExecutor method **10 times**, it will use **only a single thread to send** them. It will not create a new thread every time. Which means that the events **will be sent sequentially or synchronously**!
You can read more from [here](https://github.com/XQQ8765/Java-Concurrency-in-Practice/blob/master/Chap%206.%20Task%20Execution/6.2.%20The%20Executor%20Framework.txt):

Now see the below example with new thread

```
public void sendEventThread(Event e){
  Thread(//send the event here).start();
}
```

If you **call it 10 times**, it will create **10 new threads**. Which means, the executions will be **asynchronous**! And it **could be dangerous**, it can create a lot of threads depending on how many times you call sendEventThread functions.

*Please note that, the code are only for demonstration purpose, it might have syntax error!*
**If you find any wrong description here, I will be happy to be corrected.**

Some more information from [here](https://github.com/XQQ8765/Java-Concurrency-in-Practice/blob/master/Chap%206.%20Task%20Execution/6.2.%20The%20Executor%20Framework.txt)

> newSingleThreadExecutor. A single-threaded executor creates a single
>   worker thread to process tasks,  replacing it if it dies unexpectedly.
>   Tasks are guaranteed to be processed sequentially according to  the
>   order imposed by the task queue (FIFO, LIFO, priority order).[4]
>
> [4] Single-threaded executors also provide sufficient internal
>   synchronization to guarantee that  any memory writes made by tasks are
>   visible to subsequent tasks; this means that objects can be safely 
>   confined to the “task thread” even though that thread may be replaced
>   with another from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `ExecutorService` or `ThreadPoolExecutor` even for single digit threads. They offer more flexibility.

Have a look at `ExecutorService` & `ThreadPoolExecutor` sections in related SE questions :

[java Fork/Join pool, ExecutorService and CountDownLatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582548/java-fork-join-pool-executorservice-and-countdownlatch/33602810#33602810)

[Java's Fork/Join vs ExecutorService - when to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156599/javas-fork-join-vs-executorservice-when-to-use-which/34922218#34922218)

Assume that you have started with your own thread instead of `ExecutorService`. In future, if there is a need for supporting multiple threads, `ExecutorService` or `ThreadPoolExecutor` will offer better control and flexibility for you. You can fine-tune required number of parameters in these below APIs.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, 
TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, ThreadFactory threadFactory,
RejectedExecutionHandler handler)
```

Answer (score -1):

Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(command) will reuse previously constructed thread, it will not created new thread as in case of new Thread(). If the thread that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated, It's a kind of pool which contains a single thread which make its equivalent newFixedThreadPool(1).