# java Fork/Join pool, ExecutorService and CountDownLatch

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, countdownlatch, forkjoinpool

We have three different multi threading techniques in java - ***Fork/Join pool, Executor Service & CountDownLatch***

**Fork/Join pool** (http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/java-forkjoin-parallel-programming.html)

The Fork/Join framework is designed to make divide-and-conquer algorithms easy to parallelize. That type of algorithms is perfect for problems that can be divided into two or more sub-problems of the same type. They use recursion to break down the problem to simple tasks until these become simple enough to be solved directly. The solutions to the sub-problems are then combined to give a solution to the original problem

**ExecutorService** is an interface that extends Executor class and represents an asynchronous execution. It provides us mechanisms to manage the end and detect progress of the asynchronous tasks.

*invokeAll()* : Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete. Future.isDone() is true for each element of the returned list.

**CountDownLatch**:(http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/countdownlatch-concurrent/java-util-concurrent-countdownlatch-example/)

CountDownLatch is used in synchronisation to allow one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes.

**My assumption:**

In both these alternatives, final result will be known only after completion of all tasks/threads.

***Are these three alternatives complimentary or supplementary to each other***?

Comment: `CountDownLatch` is a versatile low-level synchronization primitive, it can be used to synchronize any kind of operations, whereas `ForkJoin` is a higher level abstraction, specifically made for recursive divide/conquer processing.

Comment: `CountDownLatch` is not a framework.  Biziclop called it "versatile".  I call it simple as dirt.  You can construct one with an initial integer value, you can decrement the value, you can get the value, and you can wait for the value to reach zero (i.e., because of being decremented by other threads).  That's _all_ it does.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After research on various multi threading frameworks , I have found answer to question from various *oracle documentation pages*

[ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

It is simple and easy to use with limited control.

I prefer this one when number of `Callable/Runnable` tasks are small in number and piling of tasks in unbounded queue does not cause pile-up in memory & degrade the performance of the system.

It hides low level details of `ThreadPoolExecutor`. It does not allow playing with other parameters ( `Bounded Queue, Rejection Handler` etc. to fine tune the performance) as in `ThreadPoolExectuor`.

[ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

```
ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, 
TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, ThreadFactory threadFactory,
RejectedExecutionHandler handler)
```

It provides more control to you. Apart from setting minimum and maximum threads, you can set queue size and make `BlockingQueue` is bounded.

If your application is constrained by number of pending Runnable/Callable tasks, you will use bounded queue by setting the max capacity. Once the queue reaches maximum capacity, you can define RejectionHandler. Java provides four types of Rejection Handler [policies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

[CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

`CountDownLatch` : This framework allows a java thread to wait until other set of threads completes their tasks.

[ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)

The `ForkJoinPool` is similar to the Java ExecutorService but with one difference.

> This enables efficient processing when most tasks spawn other subtasks (as do most ForkJoinTasks), as well as when many small tasks are submitted to the pool from external clients

```
    public ForkJoinPool(int parallelism,
            ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory factory,
            Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler handler,
            boolean asyncMode)
```

Regarding main query:

*You can use `ExecutorService.invokeAll()` or `CountDownLatch` framework or `ForkJoinPool` . *All these frameworks are complimentary to each other varying of granularity to control the execution of tasks from high level to low level*.*

Have a look at related SE questions:

[What are the advantages of using an ExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984076/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-an-executorservice)

[Java's Fork/Join vs ExecutorService - when to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156599/javas-fork-join-vs-executorservice-when-to-use-which/34922218#34922218)